# How to check if an IP address (or range) is valid

Tags: ruby

I've run across several posts to check if whether or not an IP address is valid using various gems, but none them seem to have the capability of determining if whether or not the CIDR format is being used.

For example:

```
irb(main):057:0> "192.168.1.1"   =~ Resolv::IPv4::Regex ? true : false #=> true
=> true
irb(main):058:0> "192.168.1.1/30"   =~ Resolv::IPv4::Regex ? true : false #=> true
=> false
irb(main):059:0>
```

and

```
irb(main):059:0> IPAddress.valid? "192.168.1.1"
=> true
irb(main):060:0> IPAddress.valid? "192.168.1.1/32"
=> false
```

are two of the most common ways I've seen this being used. How do I incorporate CIDR notation as well in these validation checks?

Comment: How do you define "valid"? What are the criteria to determine whether an IP address is "valid"? Is a Class D address valid? Is an RFC5737 address valid? Is an RFC1918 address valid? Is an RFC1918 address *in*valid? Is an IPv6 address valid? What about an IPv6 address supplied in non-canonical form? Is an IP address that is registered to someone else valid? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `parse` method if the `ipaddress` gem (https://github.com/ipaddress-gem/ipaddress)

Parsing a valid address:

```
3.0.0 :005 > x = IPAddress.parse "192.168.1.1/32"
 => #<IPAddress::IPv4:0x00007f92d684f010 @address="192.168.1.1", @prefix=32, @octets=[192, 168, 1, 1], @u32=3232235777>
```

Parsing an invalid address raises:

```
3.0.0 :006 > x = IPAddress.parse "192.168.1.1.1/32"
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```